# passing a value to another python module

Tags: python

I am running the script as `python test.py ab_mr1`, the output should be `"ab_mr1"` for  `branch_name`, But it is printing as emtpy value, any idea why?

`test1.py`:

```
import os
import sys

import test

def main():
    ScriptDir = os.getcwd()
    print ScriptDir
    BranchName  = sys.argv[1]
    print "BranchName"
    print BranchName
    #Update input file with external gerrits, if any
    print "Before running test1"
    test.main(BranchName) # here I am passing the variable
    print "After running test1"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`test.py`:

```
branch_name=''
def main(branch_name):
    print('In test.py, the value is: {0}', branch_name)
if __name__ == '__main__': # need this
    main(branch_name)
```

Current output:

```
('In test.py, the value is: {0}', '')
```

Expected output:

```
('In test.py, the value is: {0}', 'ab_mr1')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got confused. You are running `test.py`, **not** `test1.py`.

Run `test1.py` to have it call `test.main()`. Because you are running `test.py` it's `__main__` block is running and `branch_name` is an empty string.

Your code is otherwise working Just Fine:

```
$ python test1.py ab_mr1
/private/tmp
BranchName
ab_mr1
Before running test1
('In test.py, the value is: {0}', 'ab_mr1')
After running test1
```